# Python File Modified Time get and set over socket

Tags: python, file, time, python-3.x

I have written some code where I get the modified time of a file using

```
os.path.getmtime('path')
```

which returns some number like `965465464.19234`. I convert it to bytes and send it over socket. At the other end I read the socket and try to set this timestamp to another file using:

```
os.utime('path',(access_time, modified_time))
```

I ensure `access_time` remains the same while I try to set the `modified_time` received from socket. But `utime` expects an integer, so I truncate the number (for example: `965465464`) and then things work fine.

Am I losing any thing by truncating? How can this be made better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that the problem has to do with modified_time being float or integer. The code below should work. I did everything, but send it over the wire.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from calendar import timegm
import sys
st_info = os.stat('foo.py')
st_info.st_atime #acces time
st_info.st_mtime #modified time
mtime = st_info.st_mtime
atime = st_info.st_atime
# send over the wire
os.utime('foo.py', (atime, mtime))
```

As you can see os.utime can do just fine with floats.

mtime

Out[15]: 1322517342.0

In [16]: type(mtime)

Out[16]: float

Comment: A small doubt, in order to convert in python 3, sending over socket requires us to convert everything to bytes and then back from bytes to whatever intended. Right? So will the issue of int and float not pop in ? Thanks for your reply. Appreciate your help

Comment: the docs explicitly say: *"If you need the exact timestamps you should always use st_atime_ns, st_mtime_ns, and st_ctime_ns"*. As I understand OP wants the exact timestamps therefore integer `*_ns` attributes should be used.

Answer (score 2):

`getmtime()` returns `st_mtime`. From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.stat):

> Note: **The exact meaning and resolution of the st_atime, st_mtime, and
>   st_ctime attributes depend on the operating system and the file
>   system.** For example, on Windows systems using the FAT or FAT32 file
>   systems, st_mtime has 2-second resolution, and st_atime has only 1-day
>   resolution. See your operating system documentation for details.
>   Similarly, although st_atime_ns, st_mtime_ns, and st_ctime_ns are
>   always expressed in nanoseconds, many systems do not provide
>   nanosecond precision. On systems that do provide nanosecond precision,
>   the floating-point object used to store st_atime, st_mtime, and
>   st_ctime cannot preserve all of it, and as such will be slightly
>   inexact. **If you need the exact timestamps you should always use
>   st_atime_ns, st_mtime_ns, and st_ctime_ns.**

<sup>emphasizes mine</sup>

You could use `ns` parameter to pass the integer nanoseconds from `os.stat()` to `os.utime()`:

```
os.utime(path, ns=(access_time_ns, modified_time_ns))
```